# outer merge two dataframe by summing up one of the column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Two dataframes

eg.
data1

```
 id : [1, 2, 3]

 value: [2, 3, 5]
```

data2

```
 id : [1, 2, 4]

 value: [1, 3, 5]
```

looking for this output:

```
id : [1, 2, 3, 4]

value: [3, 6, 5, 5]
```

Comment: can you show us the shape of your dataframe? is it nested lists or rows/columns?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The 'id' and 'value' are the column name, and the list is the list of values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3],'value':[2, 3, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 4],'value':[1, 3, 5]})

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('id').sum().reset_index()
print (df)
   id  value
0   1      3
1   2      6
2   3      5
3   4      5
```